# MySQL SELECT IN with single value

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL is it very bad to do this:

```
SELECT ... WHERE foo IN ('bar')
```

instead of this...

```
SELECT ... WHERE foo = 'bar'
```

...given that this dynamically generated WHERE clause is also likely to be

```
SELECT ... WHERE foo IN ('bar', 'baz', 'buz')
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957405/speed-of-in-keyword-in-mysql-postgresql

Comment: @mcabral: I agree.  @Quassnoi's answer is the most applicable to this situation

Comment: @mcabral - out of curiosity how did you find that dupe given that 'in' is a stop word?

Comment: ye olde trick! google for 'site:stackoverflow.com  mysql in keyword'

Comment: @mcabral haha! yes, obvious once you see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that it would be converted into the same thing before execution. Either way, I would file this under 'really really low concern'.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I would worry about this.

However, because it's dynamically generated you could always do a test to see how many values you have before building the where clause.

Comment: I'm not sure either, but if there's no significant performance hit I'd rather keep the generation code clean + concise

Comment: @Rob Agar: This falls under the idea of Preoptimization.  If while profiling the app you notice a performance hit, then change it.  Otherwise just go with what you are more comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

It is much better to use, for SQL query optimization and best practices:

```
WHERE foo = 'bar' OR foo = 'baz'
```

than:

```
WHERE foo IN ('bar', 'baz')
```

Regards

Comment: that should actually be `foo = 'bar' OR foo = 'baz'`, but i don't think that changes something in performance at all

Comment: do you have a source for this? i don't mean to be rude but, i've been reading they are quite the same.

Comment: For small IN clauses there isn't an issue.  However, if you have very large
IN clauses, especially ones that vary with each execution, there is
significant issues with multipage allocators and the procedure cache.